# Twine upload TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, twine

Has anybody got an error like this when you try to upload your package ?

```
   $ twine upload dist/*
   Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
   Enter your username: MyUsername
   Enter your password: ********
   TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Edit: Got the same error again but this time to fix it I upgraded twine and it started working again.

Comment: I have `Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
 - TypeError: expected string or buffer` right now...

Comment: Updating twine did solve the issue for me (problem showed up with 1.9.1 version; just upgraded to 1.11.0).

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/342

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updating twine solved the problem for me. For this, execute the following command before doing `twine upload dist/*`:

`python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade twine`

Comment: I'm guessing your response is a command that updates twine. Since that resolved the problem for me, I'm flagging your response as the accepted answer to help other users see it.

Comment: That's correct. I edited the text accordingly to make this more clear.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after installing twine by `apt`. It seems that it installed twine for python2 and my project was python3.

So I've installed twine with pip for python3:

```sh
pip3 install twine
```

and used the following command:

```sh
python3 -m twine upload dist/*
```

Worked perfectly fine