# How to upgrade twine to version 1.11?

Tags: twine

I had the same error as [twine upload TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49806586/6597765) and checked my twine version to find out it's 1.10. However, with pip list I find that twine is version 1.11. I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade twine
```

(see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/44124))

and found that twine is already being the latest release (1.10.0-1) and could not upgrade to 1.11.

```
$ which twine
/usr/bin/twine
```

How can I upgrade twine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the exact error message you get when you try to upgrade?

Try uninstalling twine manually and then installing again, being sure to specify the 1.11 version

Comment: I decided to only use twine within my venv, so I installed it with pip and that was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the 1.11 and download the latest version